# How to catch Google Translate results (personal use)? Old techniques don't works anymore

Tags: python, html, url, urllib2

I writing a python script (personal use only) to translate a text using the terminal on linux.

I tried:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import urllib,urllib2

url="http://translate.google.com/#en|pt|love"
#url="http://www.google.com"
request=urllib2.Request(url)
answer=urllib2.urlopen(request).read()

print "request:\n",request,"\n\n"
print "answer:\n",answer,"\n\n"
```

But it isn't working. The truth if we uncomment the line
`#url="http://www.google.com"` and comment `url="http://translate.google.com/#en|pt|love"` all works.

It strange because if we copy `url="http://translate.google.com/#en|pt|love"` and paste in the browser the url will works.

So, how can I fix this to catch the results?

Answer (score 3):

Your URL contains the `en|pt|love` string as a fragment (after `#`). A fragment is intended for client-side (JavaScript) processing. It is not sent to the server. In other words, Google Translate does its job, or some part of it, in client-side JavaScript, which runs in your browser, but of course not in your Python script.

Google provides a [Translate API](https://developers.google.com/translate/) as a paid service.

Comment: Correct. Hashes are never sent to the server with the HTTP request (unless, of course, you send them separately by first retrieving on client side and then enclosing in some other HTTP request).

Comment: Use a paid service will not work to me, because, as I said, is just personal use. I would like to do this script to automates some of my tasks. About the javascript, this is interesting. Couldn't we use text brownswer like w3m to get the correct output?

Comment: w3m does not support JavaScript, although there are mentions of a w3m-js extension floating around. If you intend to use this on your personal desktop, I’d go the Selenium route.

Answer (score 2):

try Selenium, http://seleniumhq.org/
or using PyQT webkit

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import QWebView
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
web = QWebView()
web.load(QUrl("http://translate.google.com/#en|pt|love"))
web.show()
app.exec_()
print web.page().mainFrame().toPlainText().toUtf8()
```

when you close the app window, you will see what you want

Comment: PasteBT, interesting. The results really come to the terminal. Unfortunally we have to open a window. Could we not open windows and parse the results like using BeautifulSoup? I would like to output just the translation results, or the results in the element of id result_box.

Comment: @GarouDan: Comment out web.show() will hide the window, but you still need X server. That is difficult to drop X, but you can start a fake X server by using Xvfb